# rust - variable doesn't live long enough

Tags: rust, lifetime

Anyone knows why the compiler complains?

```rust
fn main() {
    struct Z<'a, 'b> {
        a: &'a i32,
        b: &'b i32,
    }

    let z: Z;
    {
        let a = 1;
        {
            let b = 2;
            z = Z { a: &a, b: &b };
            println!("{}", z.b);
        }
        println!("{}", z.a);
    }
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:12:31
   |
12 |             z = Z { a: &a, b: &b };
   |                               ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
13 |             println!("{}", z.b);
14 |         }
   |         - `b` dropped here while still borrowed
15 |         println!("{}", z.a);
   |                        --- borrow later used here
```

I am only using the `z.a` in the `println`, is this some compiler limitations?

Comment: no it's not a compiler limitation, Rust mandate this behavior. I think the compiler error message is clear and that you understand it.

Comment: nope, not a javascript programmer
z = Z { a: &a, b: &b };
int the above Z{...} should be moved to the outer scope as z is declared in the outer scope. Of course the reference to b (z.b) should not be available, as b is declared in the inner scope, but z.a should have enough lifetime. fyi this works:
let z: Z;
    {
        let a = 1;
        let b = 2;
        {
            z = Z{a: &a, b: &b};
        }
        println!("{}", z.a);
    }

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is telling you that b does not live long enough because b does, in fact, not live long enough. It's dropped (deallocated) when its scope ends, which is 'at' the inner curly brace. However, Z is still holding a reference to b when that happens, which means Z is invalid. So, for Z to exist, b must live longer.

It doesn't matter that only z.a is used, z.b is still *part of z*, and the structure as a whole doesn't make sense without it. So you *could* say it's a compiler limitation that this code won't compile, as it's technically okay, but structurally, it's not okay. A reference is being held to a value which does not exist, so the code does not compile.

Comment: thanks, yeah, I understand that Z is not structurally okay (as only z.a is valid), but no harm was done (no dereferencing of deallocated (stack) memory of z.b), and hoped the compiler will be less sensitive

Comment: @FerencDanielGráczer It's easy enough to *tell* the compiler that you won't be using `z.b`: [just put the access to `z.a` inside the `{}` block](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=242d38ba4afe6937e2d7a38cd5618472). In code where you *can't* do that -- for instance, because `Z` implements `Drop` -- the code would not have worked in the first place. Think of it not as the compiler being arbitrarily "sensitive" so much as insisting on a certain degree of explicitness from your code.

Comment: @trentcl thanks, it was just a toy example. I started to learn Rust 10 days ago, and I was wondering if my code would somehow could violate memory safety and rejected because of that, or it is rejected, because it is would be hard to implement it in the compiler to let the code pass compilation

Comment: @Daniel Generally, the purpose of defining new types is to encapsulate and provide invariants. `Z` is "the type consisting of two difference references to i32". You simply can't have that with only one reference - if one wants to separate references _not_ encapsulated together, one wouldn't use a `Z`.

Comment: @GManNickG Technically it's not true that you can't have a half-valid value - partial moves are right up that alley. The existence of partial moves shows that the OP is likely correct that the borrow checker _could_ be improved to allow the code to compile (while still preserving the semantics of Rust). The pattern as shown is either not important enough to warrant such improvement, or such a thing was indeed too hard to implement, as the OP puts it.